# Trying to edit html code in variable and write to body

Tags: jquery

Trying to edit html code in variable and write to body with the code below but doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```js
var html ='<input class="1" value="1"/><input class="2" value="2"/><input class="3" value="3"/>';

$(html).find(".1,.2").remove();
$("body").html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems here.

This line does nothing:

```
$(html).find(".1,.2").remove();
```

It creates a new temporary variable containing a jQuery wrapper around three `<input>` elements. Then it runs a `find` on this intermedia value, which cannot work, because find looks for *children* of the currently wrapped element(s). Then it `removes` any found children (which again, are none). Then, it discards the intermediate value, leaving the original `html` variable containing an unmodified string.

In order to achieve what you're trying to do, you need to wrap your HTML fragment in a root node and assign the result of your manipulations to a new variable:

```js
var html ='<input class="1" value="1"/><input class="2" value="2"/><input class="3" value="3"/>';

var $html = $("<div>" + html + "</div>");
$html.find(".1,.2").remove();
$("body").html($html.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```